# Can't return my value correctly when recursing a Binary Search Tree

Tags: javascript, recursion, binary-search-tree

I've tested to see if my trees are being inserted properly and am using pseudoclassical instantiation to make this work. My issue is that the debugger will tell me that truth is being set to true, then when I return the truth value from the end of the function I get false. I have tried everything I can think of but I can't figure out why this is happening. Here's my code that searches the binary search tree.

```js
  var valuetest;
  var truth = false;
  if (this.value === value) {
    var truth = true;
    return truth;
  } else if (value > this.value) {
    valuetest = this.right.value;
    if (valuetest === value) {
      truth = true;
      return truth;
    } else {
      this.right.contains(value);
    }
  } else {
    valuetest = this.left.value;
    if (valuetest === value) {
      truth = true;
      return truth;
    } else {
      this.left.contains(value);
    }
  }
  return truth;
  //returns false even if truth is set to true for some reason.
```

Comment: update `this.right.contains(value);` to `return this.right.contains(value);` and the same with left.

Comment: Also you're not checking for NULL (ie. end of tree)

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked, now I have to figure out the null implementation check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated lines with return. Try this snippet.

```js
  var valuetest;
  var truth = false;
  if (this.value === value) {
    var truth = true;
    return truth;
  } else if (value > this.value) {
    valuetest = this.right.value;
    if (valuetest === value) {
      truth = true;
      return truth;
    } else {
      return this.right.contains(value);
    }
  } else {
    valuetest = this.left.value;
    if (valuetest === value) {
      truth = true;
      return truth;
    } else {
      return this.left.contains(value);
    }
  }
  return truth;
  //returns false even if truth is set to true for some reason.
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to `return` the recursive call. So you see *thruth* getting true, but then one level back out of the recursion, the *truth* variable there is a different variable, and it does not get set at all.

Also, you have implemented [arm's length recursion](https://www.quora.com/What-is-arms-length-recursion) by repeating equality checks, which really is not necessary here. You can condense your code to :

```
return value === this.value  ||
       value > this.value && this.right && this.right.contains(value) ||
       value < this.value && this.left && this.left.contains(value);
```

If the value is not found, the recursion should stop. The above will work if you have built your tree in such a way that `value` is `null` or `undefined` when it represents a leaf.

Or, you might omit `left` and/or `right` properties when there are no more children in that direction. Also if the tree is built like that, the code above will work.

Or still a bit smarter:

```
const branch = this[value > this.value ? 'right' : 'left'];
return value === this.value  || branch && branch.contains(value);
```